# Derivation of $(y_2/y_1)'=0$ from the Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While reading a proof of a theorem under the section **The General Solution of the Homogeneous equation** in *Differential Equations and Transform Techniques* by George F. Simmons, it is given that

> We now assume that the Wronskian is identically zero and prove linear
> dependence. If $y_1$ is identically zero on $[a,b]$, then (as we remarked at the
> beginning of the section) the functions are linearly dependent. We may therefore assume that $y_1$ does not vanish identically on $[a,b]$, from which it follows
> by continuity that $y_1$ does not vanish at all on some subinterval $[c,d]$ of $[a,b]$.
> Since the Wronskian is identically zero on $[a,b]$, we can divide it by $y_1^2$
> to get
> $$\frac{y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'}{y_1^2}=0$$
> on $[c,d]$. This can be written in the form $(y_2/y_1)'=0$, and by integrating we obtain $y_2/y_1=k$.

So my question is how did he obtain $$(y_2/y_1)'=0$$
by dividing $y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'=0$ by $y_1^2$?

Answer (score 3):

This is the quotient rule of differentiation in reverse.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: Got it! But how did he find the technique on dividing by $y_1^2$ to get the (u/v)' result. Is it because he had that quotient rule embedded in his mind or is there some approach on getting that form? Hope my question made sense(⁠~⁠_⁠~⁠;⁠)

Comment: Also is there a way to integrate this $\frac{y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'}{y_1^2}$ to get $(y_2/y_1)$